# Creating Windows virtual machine to create .NET and IIS vagrant environment

Tags: .net, windows, macos, vagrant, virtualbox

As a front-end developer using OS X, working with Windows based developers, I want to create a dev environment that includes Windows, IIS, .NET, SQL Server and Sitecore.

The goal is to bypass creating static HTML, CSS, and JS files and instead go right into views and models files in .NET and Sitecore. Using Vagrant, I can access a localhost dev environment that will allow me to log into Sitecore and view the front-end as I develop.

I know that the old [modern.ie](http://modern.ie) site which is now [Microsoft Edge VMs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/) could provide good starter environments. Using Vagrant, I want to provision setting up various software like IIS, .NET, SQL Server and Sitecore into a VM.

If not modern.ie VMs, I am sure this can be done with any licensed Windows 10 Professional ISO. My goal is to automate this setup as much as possible with Vagrant so that after I run `vagrant up`, I have a ready dev environment for front-end development.

What process would I need to go through for this to work?

Comment: you can look at script provisioning using powershell or bat

Comment: That's true after I get into Windows. I'm trying to setup Windows on the VM before I really have a chance to use another shell within the OS. I need to have provisions that run from within Vagrant since I'll be configuring this VM from OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at shell provisioning [provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html). The scripts are run during `vagrant up` so before you get into Windows

In your Vagrantfile, you'll add

```
  ......
  config.vm.define "win_10" do |win10|
    win10.vm.box = "windows_10"

    win10.vm.provision "shell", path: "puppet/install_ariba/test/install_win_jdk.ps1"
    win10.vm.provision "shell", path: "puppet/install_ariba/test/install_browsers.ps1"
  ......
```

The `install_browsers.ps1` will look like

```
function LogWrite {
    Param ([string]$logstring)
    $now = Get-Date -format s
    Add-Content $Logfile -value "$now $logstring"
    Write-Host $logstring
}

function CheckLocation {
    Param ([string]$location)
    if (!(Test-Path  $location)) {
        throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] "Could not download to Destination $location."
    }
}

function add-host([string]$ip, [string]$hostname) {
    $hostsPath = "$env:windir\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
    $ip + "`t`t" + $hostname | Out-File -encoding ASCII -append $hostsPath
}

$Logfile = "C:\Windows\Temp\chrome-firefox-install.log"

$FF_VER="45.0.1";
$firefox_source = "https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/$FF_VER/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%20$FF_VER.exe"
$firefox_destination = "C:\Windows\Temp\firefoxinstaller.exe"

LogWrite "Starting to download files $firefox_source"
try {
    LogWrite 'Downloading Firefox...'
    (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($firefox_source, $firefox_destination)
    CheckLocation $firefox_destination
} catch [Exception] {
    LogWrite "Exception during download. Probable cause could be that the directory or the file didn't exist."
    LogWrite '$_.Exception is' $_.Exception
}

LogWrite 'Starting firefox install process.'
try {
    Start-Process -FilePath $firefox_destination -ArgumentList "-ms" -Wait -PassThru
} catch [Exception] {
    LogWrite 'Exception during install process.'
    LogWrite '$_.Exception is' $_.Exception
}

LogWrite 'Update hostfile'
add-host "192.168.90.52" "pws.app"

LogWrite 'All done. Goodbye.'
```

In this example, I download and install a specific version of FireFox as well as updating the host file. There are many examples around on the net to install soft using powershell script.

Comment: Assuming I use the Windows 10 VMs from their Microsoft Edge Dev site, these VMs don't include WinRM. How will that cause issues with this type of installation considering shell requires WinRM to do some of the installations? Will this mean we have to use our own licensed copy of Win10?

Comment: argh right I forgot, remind me why we want on our own build using packer for a better industrialization of the chain. on the modern.ie box you can install winrm and repackage the box.

Comment: Ugh, i was afraid you would say that. I was trying to have something that would provision the VM before triggering the 90 day expiration. I came across this discussion where the MSEdgeDev team is interested in feedback on this: https://www.reddit.com/r/vagrant/comments/3pyyi2/modernie_for_vagrant_reloaded/

Comment: right did not see that .. I use the [packer](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/packer-windows/) which is mentioned and works well but you need to renew the process every 90 days (a good night work fully automated, not too bad) .. maybe you can reach them on the twitter account mentioned

Comment: I reached out to them, they seem receptive and if we keep them accountable they might actually update the Vagrant VMs to include missing features mentioned in the Reddit link above. So there's a little progress!

Comment: Hey, I was playing around with this example Vagrantfile code that you provided and `$_.Exception` doesn't return anything valuable. It just says `$_.Exception is` without anything returning. Should that value be a variable of some kind?

Comment: It looks like `$_.Exception` won't display anything unless it's preceded by `write-host`.

Comment: hum weird, sounds like string concatenation does not work, maybe `LogWrite "Exception is $_.Exception"` or directly `LogWrite $_.Exception`